# Como añadir filas y copiar a la última fila vacía

Tags: excel, vba

Estaba intentado hacer una macro que, en base a la cantidad de celdas que superen el valor de 25, me añada filas tantas veces como eso suceda en otra hoja y posteriormente me copie otros valores que aparecen en celdas adyacentes y se ponga en la última fila. Mi problema es que en vez de la última fila se copia a celdas que no quiero que vaya. También necesito copiar el formato de la fila superior ya que es una tabla.

```
Dim numero As String
Dim NumFila As String

Range("A7").End(xlDown).Select
numero = 7
NumFila = ActiveCell.Row

    Do Until NumFila = numero + 1
        
        On Error Resume Next
        
        If Worksheets("Realizar pedido").Range("F" & numero).Value >= 25 Then
            Worksheets("Hoja1").Range("A8").EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlShiftAbove
            Worksheets("Realizar pedido").Range("B" & numero).Copy
            Worksheets("Hoja1").Range("D" & numero).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    
                
        End If
        numero = numero + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

¿Alguien me echa una mano con esto?
Cabe destacar que soy nuevo en esto y no tengo conocimientos en programación.

Answer (score 0):

Por favor, lee [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y no olvides leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Visita también el  [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Estás preguntando demasiadas cosas en una sola pregunta, básicamente tu pregunta ahora mismo es del tipo "por favor, trabaja para mí gratis desarrollando TODO mientras yo no hago nada". Procura hacer preguntas específicas.

Sobre tu código, hay varias maneras de resolverlo. Yo lo hecho con matrices.

Lo primero, evita usar `On Error Resume NExt`porque es una instrucción que **oculta** los errores, pero siguen sucediendo.

Lo segundo, mi código copia todos los valores de la columna B a la columna A de otra hoja, siempre y cuando en F el valor sea 25 o más.

Tendrás que adaptar el código a tus necesidades. Sobre el formato, investiga o abre una nueva pregunta.

```
Sub test()
Dim WkOrigen As Worksheet
Dim WkDestino As Worksheet
Dim MiMatriz As Variant
Dim UF As Long
Dim i As Long

Set WkOrigen = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Realizar pedido")
Set WkDestino = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Hoja1")

'última fila no vacía en F

UF = WkOrigen.Range("F" & WkOrigen.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'todos los datos del rango B:F a una matriz
MiMatriz = WkOrigen.Range("B7:F" & UF).Value

'ahora de la matriz solamente vuelco aquellos que F=>25
'empiezo pegando en la primera celda vacía de a, que será la última no vacía de A +1

UF = WkDestino.Range("A" & WkDestino.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

For i = LBound(MiMatriz) To UBound(MiMatriz) Step 1
    If MiMatriz(i, 5) >= 25 Then
        WkDestino.Range("A" & UF).Value = MiMatriz(i, 1)
        UF = UF + 1
    End If
Next i

Erase MiMatriz
Set WkOrigen = Nothing
Set WkDestino = Nothing

End Sub
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]